# Set Current State of Spring StateMachine

Tags: spring-statemachine

I am starting to use Spring Statemachine and I am having some trouble managing the state of my objects.

My Statemachine is of type StateMachine.

My business object, Shipment, has an enum property (state) of type ShipmentState, which should hold the state-machine state of the episode. Here is my desired workflow:

- Load a Shipment from the database.
- **Set the current state of the Statemachine from the ShipmentState that
  is in that Shipment instance.**
- Send an event to the Statemachine.
- Get the resultant state from the Statemachine (post event) and set
  the ShipmentState in my Shipmentinstance.
- Save the Shipment instance.

**The problem is: How do I set the current state of an existing StateMachine?**

My current approach is this one: For every event, create a new StateMachine instance (using a StateMachineBuilder) specifying the initial state according to a Shipment instance. For example:

```
@Service
public class StateMachineServiceImpl implements IStateMachineService {

    @Autowired
    private IShipmentService shipmentService;

    @Override
    public StateMachine<ShipmentState, ShipmentEvent> getShipmentStateMachine(Shipment aShipment) throws Exception {

        Builder<ShipmentState, ShipmentEvent> builder = StateMachineBuilder.builder();

        builder.configureStates().withStates()
            .state(ShipmentState.S1)
            .state(ShipmentState.S2)
            .state(ShipmentState.S3)
            .initial(shipmentService.getState())
            .end(ShipmentState.S4);

        builder.configureTransitions().withExternal().source(ShipmentState.S1).target(ShipmentState.S1)
                .event(ShipmentEvent.S3).action(shipmentService.updateAction()).and().withExternal()
                .source(ShipmentState.S1).target(ShipmentState.S2).event(ShipmentEvent.S3)
                .action(shipmentService.finalizeAction()).and().withExternal().source(ShipmentState.S3)
                .target(ShipmentEvent.S4).action(shipmentService.closeAction()).event(ShipmentEvent.S5);

        return builder.build();
    }

}
```

What do you think of my approach?

Comment: [Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/reference/#sm-persist) don't recommend it: Building an instance of a state machine is a relatively heavy operation. Consequently, if you need to (for example) handle an arbitrary state change in a database by using a state machine, you need to find a better and faster way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

There is no issue with the approach. You can reset the state machine to particular state using the below code.

```java
stateMachine.getStateMachineAccessor().doWithAllRegions(access -> access
          .resetStateMachine(new DefaultStateMachineContext<>(state, null, null,null)));
```

You can pass the arguments to the `DefaultStateMachineContext` according to your use case.

Comment: [Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/reference/#sm-persist) don't recommend it: *Building an instance of a state machine is a relatively heavy operation. Consequently, if you need to (for example) handle an arbitrary state change in a database by using a state machine, you need to find a better and faster way to do it.*